# I can load css file with node express, but it doesn't work, some css file can work

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express

I set`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` in my `app.js`

and now I use `bootstrap.css` and myself css file `main.css`

**index.html：**

```
  ┊ <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  ┊ <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href='bootstrap/theme/bootstrap.united.css' />
  ┊ <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href='bootstrap/css/main.css' />
```

**main.css:**

```
  1 body {
  2   background-color: red;
  3 }
```

and my file's tree is:

```
public
├── bootstrap
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── bootstrap.css
│   │   └── bootstrap.min.css
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── bootstrap.js
│   │   └── bootstrap.min.js
│   └── theme
│       └── bootstrap.united.css
├── css
│   └── main.css
└── jQuery
    └── jquery-1.12.0.min.js
```

my node server is `127.0.0.1:3000`

in my chrome, the `bootstrap.united.css` can work,
but `main.css` can not work,
and I can load it in `http://10.0.8.88:3000/css/main.css`

why `main.css` has been loaded, but doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like in your href of your main.css link, you started the file path with 'bootstrap' but the css folder begins outside of that branch.